# Where does Redux fit into the front/back end spectrum?

Tags: redux

From my understanding Redux is a state container that helps you manage data flow within your application.

I read the following in the docs 'Redux can be used on the server for server side rendering'.

In the case where you are using Redux with React to manage the flow of data relied on by your UI where exactly does Redux fit within the front/back end spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is not too important, but it depends on whatever use you give it. However, apparently it is now called an [isomorphic](http://isomorphic.net/javascript) framework/library. Which means it runs both on the server side and the client side. Here's a [starting list](http://isomorphic.net/libraries). Here is an [example](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.ahiawqblk).